# BeautifulSoup prints none even the content is there

Tags: python-3.x, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to build a hackernews scraper but when i ran my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("https://news.ycombinator.com/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')

print(soup.find(id="score_23174015"))
```

I  am Not getting that why beautifulsoup is returning none all the time to me i am still learning so yeah i am new to python3 as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the url, but there is no element with id = 23174015.

Anyway, try this code if you want to find element with attributes.

```
soup.find(attrs = {'id':"score_23167794"})
```